# How to implement static virtual member function

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods, virtual-functions

**TL/DR: Is there a (more convenient) way to implement such functionality?**

I have to invoke the same static code for both class-type and class-instance represented by reference to base:

```
int main()
{
    // Invokes on class
    bar<C1>(); // invokes C1::foo()
    bar<C2>(); // invokes C2::foo()

    // Invokes on instance
    bar(C1()); // invokes C1::foo()
    bar(C2()); // invokes C2::foo()
}
```

But the problem is that I can't implement that without some code duplication. For each derived class I have to write both static and virtual methods. Static - because I can't invoke a virtual method on class, and virtual, which calls static - because there's no way to distinguish object behaviour except by virtual methods:

```
template<typename T>
void bar()
{
    T::foo();
}

void bar(A const &r)
{
    r.foo();
}
```

Thus, my workaround to solve the problem of duplicating code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

template<typename derived_T>
class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const
    {
        derived_T::foo();
    }
};

class C1 : public B<C1>
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "C1::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C2 : public B<C2>
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "C2::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This approach works perfectly, but it has at least two inconveniences.

Firstly, I had to introduce an auxiliary template class B with implemented virtual method.

Secondly, every inheritance chain (from B to final class) must consists of templates that makes impossible using any intermediate class as pointer/reference type. eg. A <- B <- T1 <- T2 <- C , T1 and T2 must be template classes to provide C::foo().

Comment: Being both static and virtual makes no sense. A member function can be either static or virtual, not both. Reason being that virtual functions are bound to an *object*, an instance of a class, while static functions are bound to a *class* and not dependent on specific instances.

Comment: in your example there is no duplicated code..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: until you has the same task. Read at least the beginning of the post.

Comment: @amine: Yes, you correctly noticed. But I have the problems that I explained at the end of post.

Comment: Okay, fair point. Then I counter with, what is your use-case? What is the *original* problem you want to solve with a solution like this? Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You will be laughing. I had to provide static virtual property, eg. description of a class.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. What is the problem you are trying to solve? And why you claim you have solved it if your code doesn't compile? What am I missing?

Comment: @PaoloM: I tested that approach in GCC 4.8.3 and VC2010. It works.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tested?

Comment: @PaoloM http://textuploader.com/a10ac
There is only changing in name of virtual. For GCC only. In MSVC it works as just "foo".

Comment: Don't cry while down voting. I sometimes have the same effect: They did not understand the question and vote. It's normal to SO! Forget about! I have no idea why down voting is possible without a useful comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is CRTP with base class injection.

```
template <typename T, typename... Bases> 
struct CRTPFooInjector : Bases... 
{
    virtual void vfoo() { T::foo(); }
};
```

This is your injector template. It only implements the virtual version of foo, nothing else.

```
struct Base: CRTPFooInjector<Base>
{
    static int foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()" << std::endl; }
};


struct Der1 : CRTPFooInjector<Der1, Base>
{
    static int foo() { std::cout << "Der1::foo()" << std::endl; }
};


struct Der2 : CRTPFooInjector<Der2, Base>
{
    static int foo() { std::cout << "Der2::foo()" << std::endl; }
};


struct Der12 : CRTPFooInjector<Der12, Der1, Der2>
{
    static int foo() { std::cout << "Der12::foo()" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now instead of your normal hierarchy `Base <- Der1 <- Der12` you have a slightly different one `Injector <- Base <- Injector <- Der1 <- Injector <- Der12`, but this should be transparent for most users.

If you need to mix in some virtual base classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct Virtual : virtual T
{
};

struct Der1 : CRTPFooInjector<Der1, Virtual<Base>> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you a several static methods, that your derived classes are fixed, you may use visitor pattern:

```
class IAVisitor;
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void accept(IAVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};
struct C1; struct C2; /*..*/; struct Cn;
struct IAVisitor
{
    virtual ~IAVisitor() = default;
    virtual visit(C1&) = 0;
    virtual visit(C2&) = 0;
    //...
    virtual visit(Cn&) = 0;
};

struct C1 : A
{
    void accept(IAVisitor& visitor) override {visitor.visit(*this);};
    static void foo();
};
// Similar code for C2, Cn

template <typename F>
struct AVisitor_F : IAVisitor
{
    AVisitor_F(F f) : f(f) {}
    void visit(C1& a) override { f(a); }
    void visit(C2& a) override { f(a); }
    //...
    void visit(Cn& a) override { f(a); }

    F f;
};
```

And with

```
struct FooCaller
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator () (const T&) const
    {
        T::foo();
    }
};
```

And finally:

```
AVisitor_F<FooCaller> fooVisitor;
a.accept(fooVisitor);
```

Comment: Nah. CRTP looks prettier.